# Логические операции

Tags: php

Как сделать такой запрос:

```
  if($num == 5 "или" $num == 6 "или" $num == 7){
echo "Данное число ровно 5,6,7 ^^";
}
else{
echo "Данное число не ровно 5,6,7 =Р";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  if($num == 5 or $num == 6 or $num == 7){
echo "Данное число ровно 5,6,7 ^^";
}
else{
echo "Данное число не ровно 5,6,7 =Р";
}

or в переводе с английского = ИЛИ
and в переводе с английского = И
```

Comment: or в переводе с английского = ИЛИ
and в переводе с английского = И

Comment: Ага, ошибка.

Comment: @exec В чем же?

Comment: @LordySL да ни в чем.

Answer (score 1):

Можете ознакомиться - 
[Логические операторы](http://www.php.ru/manual/language.operators.logical.html).

Answer (score 0):

Если проф. программист советую использовать:
|| - Или
&& - И